# Make WCF REST service public when hsoted on virtual machine's IIS8

Tags: .net, wcf, hosting, public, iis-8

I have MS Server 2012 on a virtual machine and I'm hosting a WCF REST service in IIS8, what do I need to do exactly to make the service public? I have a static IP, and I configured my router the forward calls to my external IP:PORT to the service's IP:PORT , but I think that because it is a virtual machine something i wrong?

Comment: And when you try to call it you get an error saying? Can you browser the service on the local network?

Comment: I can browse the service localy ,but outside the local network Google Chrome says Oops! Can't find!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need a public IP-address provided by your ISP. And then you need to set you router/firewall to forward request to your service and port. You need to config so that the client call the public domain-name for your service, internally you service can expose it's endpoint on the local network (localhost). Please add more information (like web.configs, stack traces) to get a better answer.